# We will forever be in the service for our King in French?

Tags: verbes, articles, adjectifs, questions

How to say " We will forever be in the service of our King. or " You forever be our King " in French?

Comment: try to write your own answer to this question and after that ask someone to proofread that

Answer (score 1):

Very basically,

> À jamais vous serez notre Roi !

would be one way.  You could also say,

> Nous vous servirons, vous notre Roi, à jamais !

Comment: "vous" plutôt que "toi", on tutoie jamais un roi x) sinon la première est bien !

Comment: C'est bien vrai.  Je vais l'éditer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

> Vive à jamais, vive le Roi !

From the song "[Vive le Roi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vive_le_Roi_!_(chanson))" (1814).